# Move AD Users with Input from Two-Column CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

So I've got a little snippet of code I'm trying to import data and ultimately move the users to another OU.  The CSV has two columns with headers, User - which is populated with user names,  and OU - which is populated with the OU that the user should be moved to.

EX:
User     OU
smithja  OU=Employees,OU=002,OU=Offices,DC=Domain,DC=com
frankro  OU=Employees,OU=032,OU=Offices,DC=Domain,DC=com

I keep getting the error about cannont convert 'system.object[]' to the type 'microsoft.activedirectory.management.aduser' required by parameter 'Identity'.  Any assistance is appreciated.

```
# Import CSV  
$Move = Import-Csv -Path "F:\Desktop\MoveMe.csv"

$Imported_csv | ForEach-Object { 
    get-aduser -Identity $Move.User | move-adobject -TargetPath $Move.OU -whatif
    Echo "User: " $Move.User "-" $Move.OU
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting what you are getting is because your are not passing the right info and you have some other errors.

You do not have a populated varialbe called $Imported_csv. You have a populated variable called $Move.

Your block should look something like this...

```
$Move = Import-Csv -Path "F:\Desktop\MoveMe.csv"

$Move  | ForEach-Object { 
    get-aduser -Identity $_.User | move-adobject -TargetPath $_.OU -whatif
    'User:  ' + $_.User + '- ' +$_.OU
    }
```

Writing to screen is the default, so, no real need for echo (except out of habit 8^}) which of course is an alias.

```
Get-Alias -Name echo
CommandType     Name 
Alias           echo -> Write-Output
```

Comment: Thank you.  That's exactly what I needed.  In addition to your recommendations I also had a stray " symbol in my csv file.  I've been able to do exactly what I needed to with your help.